# Need Datatables's column visibility in my KeenThemes datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables, metronic

First question here on SO and not very familiar with datatables, so please bear with me if I'm leaving out info!

So I am using [Metronic's/KeenThemes's plugin](https://keenthemes.com/metronic/?page=docs&section=html-components-datatable) to show a datatable and I want to use Datatables's column visibility implementation to show/hide certain columns and save the column visibility state, as demonstrated here: https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/column_visibility/simple.html

I am particularly interested in this part then:

*Datatables's example code*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'colvis'
        ]
    } );
} );
```

So KeenTheme's documentation just has an 'API methods' section in their [documentation](https://keenthemes.com/metronic/?page=docs&section=html-components-datatable) page but no explanation of how/where to implement it. I am confused as to where to apply the above piece of code and how to implement other datatable methods.

*index.js*

```js
 var datatable = $('#kt_datatable').KTDatatable({
    // datasource definition
    data: {
      type: 'remote',
      source: {
        read: {
          method: 'GET',
          url: //getUrl
          // return data etc etc
        }
      }
    },
    layout: {
      //layout
    },
    // more stuff
    columns: [
      {
        field: 'id',
        title: '',
        sortable: false,
        visible: true,
        width: 20,
        type: 'number',
        selector: { class: 'kt-checkbox--solid' },
        textAlign: 'center',
      },
      // more columns
    ],
  })
```

*index.volt (html)*:

```html
<div id="kt_datatable"></div>
```

Any ideas how to implement this .DataTable code in this KT Datatable? Thanks for your help!